# How to set cron job for php script in ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I want set up a cronjob for php script for every 2minutes in my ubuntu machine for this i have found the below link for reference but i am getting following error and i am not getting it how to resolve this error.

Link for reference to set cronjob

https://askubuntu.com/questions/177971/how-can-i-set-up-a-php-script-to-run-via-cron

**First error**:
    when i run a php script using command line i have got this error
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php on line 2.But when i run this script on browser it is working fine.i dont know how to solve this.

Command for php script:php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php

**Second error**:
when i run a cronjob command on terminal it shows me this error

```
bash: */2: No such file or directory
```

Cronjob command:`*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php` /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php

Comment: The `*/2 * * * * ` is just for crontab. You can run from the command line with: `/usr/local/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php`

Comment: As for the first error, it sounds like you don't have the php mysql module installed. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: for first error when i hit php script on browser it gives me the right output not getting any error but on cammand only it is giving mysql error and for second error when i run this command /usr/local/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php it give me this error bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory.

Comment: Then your php is installed somewhere else. Try typing `which php` to find out where. Then replace the `/usr/local/bin/php` with what that command tells you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are executing the same file and getting different output via shell and your browser, it's most likely you have different versions of PHP installed. Which is why you are getting `undefined function mysql_connect()` because, you are referencing `php 5.5.0+` to run your cronjob.

The solution is to first check where php is installed.

```
$ whereis php
```

Then try to check the versions using `php -v` and `/usr/local/bin/php -v`

If all is okay, and you have `php 5.5.0` or above, you can simple remove `mysql_` functions and use instead mysqli/PDO.

At the end, your path should be like this.

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /path/to/cronjob.php
```

Comment: Hi after running this command php -v it is showing this type of warning on command line PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/msql.so' and my php version is PHP 5.5.9

Comment: What about the other one? `/usr/local/bin/php -v`? Anyway, your problem is that, mysql has been deprecated since `5.5.0` so you don't have mysql, and you can't install it. Your only option is to use either `mysqli` or PDO. So, whatever you have in `cronjob.php` it should be changed to use other than mysql. Or in short, remove all `mysql_*` function in there.

Comment: first of all in my machine /usr/bin/php -v this command is running successfully then after that i have remove all the mysql function from cronjob.php but after that when i try to run php script php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php it gives this error Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ezypayzy/cronjob.php on line 8

Comment: Of-couse you'll get that error. Everything inside php is made as extension, even the sessions are extensions by enabled by default, so you need to install or enable mysqli.  How did you install php in the first place? Did you use remicollet, webtatic or compiled it from source?